# How to add Cognito authorization to API request? So that Lambdas can access it

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I want to add Cognito authorization to my API request so that the API Gateway can pass the information on to my Lambdas. I have read in other threads that I should add the id token as authorization header, so that is what I have tried so far.

I have tried the following:

```
fetch('api/public/libraries/sign-out-discourse', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers([
        // I get the idToken from CognitoUser.getSession => getIdToken()
        ['Authorization', idToken],
    ]),
})
```

I get the error message

```
{"message":"'Object]' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: '[object Object]'."}
```

I have tried the following:

```
fetch('api/public/libraries/sign-out-discourse', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers([
        // I get the idToken from CognitoUser.getSession => getIdToken().getJwtToken()
        ['Authorization', jwtToken],
    ]),
})
```

I get the error message:

```
{"message":"Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header. Authorization=eyJraWQiOiJOemhFe..."}
```

What is the right way to pass authorization information to the api?

Comment: Not sure if it's the same issue, I had a similar one - I created an Authorizer under the required API. Provide a name, attach to a Cognito user pool. Set the Token Source as Authorization. Then goto the requests / methods under resources. For each method (GET/POST/PUT), underMethod Execution heading, Settings -> Authorization -> <name_of_authorizer_you_created_earlier>. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution may be a little too complex by utilizing the New Headers() method.

Try this:

```
fetch('api/public/libraries/sign-out-discourse', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Authorization': jwtToken
    }
});
```